# How to get the arguments from a method call on a mocked object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a unit test where the setup mocks a client like so:

```
def setUp(self):
  self.mock_client = mock.patch.object(module_name, 'ClientClassName', autospec=True).start()
```

Then in my test I have a faked return value:

```
def myTest(self):
  self.mock_client.my_method.return_value = ...
```

Now I want to get the arguments that `my_method` was called with, however I've been tearing my hair out trying to access them. It seems that I can't just do:

```
mock_args, mock_kwargs = self.mock_client.my_method.call_args
```

This gives me back First off why doesn't this work? I did make a little headway and found that:

```
self.mock_client.method_calls[0]
```

will give me back a call object that looks like `call().my_method(...the arguments)`, but I have been trying for hours to get access to the individual arguments and cant seem to do it. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Call args are just accessed with subscription on the `mock.call` object, i.e. `__getitem__`.

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock 
>>> m = MagicMock() 
>>> m(123, xyz="hello") 
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='140736989479888'>
>>> m("another call")   
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='140736989479888'>
>>> m.call_args_list
[call(123, xyz='hello'), call('another call')]
>>> m.call_args_list[0][0]  
(123,)
>>> m.call_args_list[0][1]  
{'xyz': 'hello'}
```

Item 0 will be a tuple of args, and item 1 will be a dict of kwargs. Attribute access also works, like a namedtuple (item 0 is attribute "args", and item 1 is attribute "kwargs"). If you only need to access the most recent call, you can use `call_args` instead of `call_args_list`.

Note that accessing the call args *items* directly is usually not required, you can use an assertion against another call instance in the tests:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import call  
>>> m(k=123)
<MagicMock name='mock()' id='140736989479888'>
>>> assert m.call_args == call(k=123)  # pass
>>> assert m.call_args == call(k=124)  # fail
AssertionError
```

Or an even higher level, you can use `m.assert_has_calls` on the mock directly.

When mocking *methods*, whether the mock calls have `self` or not can be influenced by autospec:

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> class A(object):
...     def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         pass
... 
>>> with mock.patch("__main__.A.f") as m:
...     a = A()
...     a.f('without autospec', n=1)
... 
>>> m.call_args
call('without autospec', n=1)
>>> with mock.patch("__main__.A.f", autospec=True) as m:
...     a = A()
...     a.f('with autospec', n=2)
... 
>>> m.call_args
call(<__main__.A object at 0x7fffe3d4e6a0>, 'with autospec', n=2)
```

This is discussed in more detail in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-unbound-methods).

Comment: Sorry I'm slightly confused. There I have a client object which is mocked using autospec which has the `my_method` method. I am have trouble getting the call args on the my_method calls. Do I have to make the method call into a mock itself?

Comment: I am also interested in that topic! I want to check some of the properties of the instances, with which the function was called. Any way to get the "self" pointer of a call?

Comment: @Silverdust When you have mocked the method `with patch("mod.Class.method") as m` then it's no longer a bound method, so the "self" was not actually passed. If you want to access the self you may want to use patch.object on the class or use an autospec, as described in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-unbound-methods). I've edited the answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to wim's answer, you can actually dig down fairly deeply into this arguments, although sometimes you seem to find a string instead of a real object.

The main point to understand is that when you iterate through `my_mock.call_args_list` you get objects of type `unittest.mock._Call`. These can indeed be compared to `call(...)` objects which you have created yourself. But that's not all.

`unittest.mock._Call` is itself iterable, and consists of 2 elements: one is a tuple, the other is a dict. These are none other than the `*args` and `**kwargs` passed to the mock method.

Given that this is, as far as I can make out, completely undocumented in the docs, I suppose it is not beyond the bounds of possibility that this could break one day. It does often prove handy to know though, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `autosepc=True`, then you can access the call args like so:

```py
     mock_func = mock.patch('my_package.func', autospec=True)
     # Some code that calls the mock method.
     first_call = mock_func.mock_calls[0]
     # You can now access the 'args' of the call by index, notice that args[0]
     # is the call object, so the first positional parameter will be args[1], the second args[2] etc...
     print('My first call's second argument:', first_call.args[2])
```